# Python, base64, float

Tags: python-3.x, base64

Do you have any idea how to encode and decode a float number with base64 in Python.
I am trying to use

```
response='64.000000'
base64.b64decode(response)
```

the expected output is `'AAAAAAAALkA='` but i do not get any output for float numbers.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right expected output? When I convert your output to a float I get 15.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Base64 encoding is only defined for byte strings, so you have to convert your number into a sequence of bytes using `struct.pack` and then base64 encode that. The example you give looks like a base64 encoded little-endian double. So (for Python 2):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<d', 64.0).encode('base64')
'AAAAAAAAUEA=\n'
```

For the reverse direction you base64 decode and then unpack it:

```
>>> struct.unpack('<d', 'AAAAAAAALkA='.decode('base64'))
(15.0,)
```

So it looks like your example is 15.0 rather than 64.0.

For Python 3 you need to also use the `base64` module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> import base64
>>> base64.encodebytes(struct.pack('<d', 64.0))
b'AAAAAAAAUEA=\n'
>>> struct.unpack('<d', base64.decodebytes(b'AAAAAAAALkA='))
(15.0,)
```