# Convert float32 bytes to base64 encoded bytes

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, base64

I have a float value `16.75` which needs to be encoded into base64 binary.

I am using the website https://cryptii.com/pipes/binary-to-base64 as a reference for validation.
`16.75` encoded into 32bit floating point format results in `01000001 10000110 00000000 00000000` which gets a base64 encoding value of `QYYAAA==`

Using the accepted answer from [Python, base64, float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914544/python-base64-float) unfortunately leads me to a different answer still.

```
xx = base64.encodebytes(struct.pack('<d', 16.75))
print(xx) #b'AAAAAADAMEA=\n'
xx = struct.unpack('<d', base64.decodebytes(xx))
print(xx) #(16.75,)
```

Can someone guide me where am I going wrong?
Do post your questions in comments - will try to answer as early as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is the differences in byte order and size of float.

Python floats are doubles. The binary you're feeding into the Cryptii website is a float32 representation.

To match the answer you were looking up, you'd need to create the struct using `"!f"` (big-endian float32)

```py
a = base64.encodebytes(struct.pack('!f', 16.75)) 
print(a) # b'QYYAAA==\n'
```

To get cryptii to return the answer you were creating in python with your example, you'd need to convert the float to binary using `"<d"` (little-endian double):

```py
print(''.join('{:0>8b}'.format(c) for c in struct.pack('<d', 16.75)))
```

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000011000001000000
```